# How to use laspass-cli to view a password?

Tags: lastpass

[Lastpass-cli](https://github.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli) is the command-line interface of the Lastpass password manager. It can be downloaded by typing

> sudo apt install lastpass-cli

in the terminal of GNU/Linux, Cygwin and Mac OS X system.
It is invoked by typing 'lpass'.

I have logged in using my username, master password, 2FA key.
I am trying to access using lpass one of the passwords stored in my Lastpass vault.
I know both the username and rough structure of the URL.
I tried lpass show
But I am unable to decipher the man page to decide what should I type to get the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the password just run

```
lpass show YOUR_KEY
```

If you already know the key name, if not you can combine it using grep to find you secret password name.

Check this tutorial to learn how to use `lpass` cli
https://yallalabs.com/linux/how-to-install-lastpass-cli-linux.